# How do I add nl2br and htmlentities in this code

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm in need of some help. How can I output the nl2br() and htmlentities() functions into my code? Both need to be applied to 'content' but htmlentities to 'title'.

```
<?php
$sql = "
    SELECT    
        post.id AS postid, post.title AS title, post.created, 
        DATE_FORMAT(Created, '%d-%m-%Y') AS created,
        post.content AS content, post.image AS image,
        post.alttext AS alttext, blog.id, blog.blogname
    FROM
        post
    LEFT JOIN  
        blog ON post.blogid = blog.id
    WHERE      
        blogid = \"" .(int)$_GET['id'] . "\"
    ORDER BY   
        postid DESC";

$results = $db->query($sql);

if ($results->num_rows) {
    while ($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        echo "<hr>
                <h3>{$row->title}</h3>
                <p>{$row->created}</p>
                <p>
                    <div id='blog-image'>
                        <img src='images/{$row->image}' alt='{$row->alttext}'>
                    </div>
                    {$row->content}
                </p>";
    }
} else {
    echo 'No Results';
}
?>
```

Comment: So you know how to apply `(int)` to `(int)$_GET['id']`, but don't know how to apply `nl2br()` and `htmlentities()`? hint, you would use a similar method with the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a new variable for that:

```
if ($results->num_rows) {
    while ($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $title = htmlentities($row->title);
        $content = nl2br(htmlentities($row->content));
        echo "<hr>
            <h3>{$title}</h3>
            <p>{$row->created}</p>
            <p>
                <div id='blog-image'>
                    <img src='images/{$row->image}' alt='{$row->alttext}'>
                </div>
                {$content}
            </p>
        ";
    }
}
```

Or break the string:

```
if ($results->num_rows) {
    while ($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        echo "<hr>
            <h3>". htmlentities($row->title) ."</h3>
            <p>{$row->created}</p>
            <p>
                <div id='blog-image'>
                    <img src='images/{$row->image}' alt='{$row->alttext}'>
                </div>
                ". nl2br(htmlentities($row->content)) ."
            </p>
        ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The neatest way is to abstract the fetch process, so that the fact that data needs demangling, is abstracted away from the view process which draws the result.
Add a function :-

```
function demangle_row($row) {
  $row->content = nl2br($row->content);
  $row->content = htmlentities($row->content);
  $row->title   = htmlentities($row->title);
}
```

Now change the while statement, to use the above code so

```
While($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
```

becomes

```
While($row = demangle_row($results->fetch_object())) {
```

Comment: you could do `function demangle_row(&$row)` so can just `demangle_row($results->fetch_object());` and `While($row = $results->fetch_object()) {` - makes more readable code

Comment: What you're saying won't work.  If you're to change the function to use the parameter by reference, you still need to assign it, and pass it in.  Hence demangle_row($results->fetch_object()) will fail with a 'can't pass function return value by reference' or something.

Comment: However if you did change it to pass by reference you could have demangle_row($row); as the first line in the while loop.  There are 3 ways of doing it. 1:as a chained function in the while statement (as I suggested), 2:as a chained function in the while loop ($row = demangle_row($row);), or 3:as a reference function in the while loop. I find pass by reference functions harder to read.  Generally I understand chains, as a filter, instinctively (javascript does this A LOT), whereas a flying function isn't obviously processing the variable passed to it. It's debatable whether option 2 is better.